# I am getting an ArithmeticException Error for dividing by zero. But I am not. Why?

Tags: java

Here is the coding question for which I am trying to solve

> Write a program that reads two numbers aa and bb from the keyboard and calculates and outputs to the console the arithmetic average of all numbers from the interval [a; b][a;b], which are divisible by 33.

**Sample Input 1:**
  -5
  12

**Sample Output 1:**
  4.5

Here is my Code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        double average = 0;
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
```

[image]

Problem: Throws Arithmetic Exception

What is the problem?

Comment: Is that all the code?

Comment: There is not division in your (incomplete) code example...

Comment: that code cannot possibly throw that exception

Comment: Please don't post code images, readers may want to copy paste your code in order to try it... Why haven't you just written the remaining part? You obviously started to provide code the correct way.

Comment: Paste your code, not an image of your code. Also, when i equals zero then you have a div by zero error. If a=-5 and b is greater than zero, you a guaranteed to have a div by zero error.

Comment: One more thing, x/3 is integer division, perhaps you want x%3 which helps determine if the number is divisible by three.

Comment: You are deciding by zero here: `average = (a + b) / x;` because x is zero when I is zero, which will happen in the example.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable i loops from -5 to 12. Then, you divide (a + b) / i (line 14).

0 is between -5 and 12. Thus, you will eventually divide by zero.

(I assume that line 13 is supposed to prevent this, but the way you have written it, it does not. In fact, 0 is among the very few values of i for which line 14 will actually be executed.)

Answer (score 2):

According to your sample input and sample output, you need to add all the numbers in the range that are divisible by 3 and divide that total by how many different numbers are in the range.

Between -5 and 12, the numbers that are divisible by 3 are:

> -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12

When you add them all together, you get 27.
And there are 6 different numbers altogether.
So the average is 27 divided by 6 which gives 4.5

Now for the code.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RangeAvg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter lower bound: ");
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter upper bound: ");
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        int lower = Math.min(a, b);
        int upper = Math.max(a, b);
        int total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
                total += i;
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("total = " + total);
        System.out.println("count = " + count);
        if (count > 0) {
            double average = (double) total / count;
            System.out.println("average = " + average);
        }
        else {
            System.out.printf("No numbers divisible by 3 between %d and %d%n", lower, upper);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a sample run:

```
Enter lower bound: -5
Enter upper bound: 12
-3
0
3
6
9
12
total = 27
count = 6
average = 4.5
```

Comment: Nice answer with a good explanation. Just one littel thing: You may want to check if count is 0 before calculating the average.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited the code accordingly.